# Like statement with quotes in sqlite database query?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

Hello Developers,
               i am working with android sqlite database here i have some confusion with database query with like statement ,below i am giving an example of how the query look like-

```
String query_al_hilites="select  HighlightedWord from tablexyz Where BookTitle=? and HighlightedWord LIKE ?";

        Cursor cur_get_all_highlites=db.rawQuery( query_al_hilites, new String[] {open_title,"'%"+search_word+"%'"});
```

but my problem is that here i am binding string searchword with' ' or "" but some  times search word contain that ' and " so query breaks ,please seggest me any way to avoid these kind of query breaks.

Thanks

Comment: Please tell me how to bind the string with like statement which can contaion both kind of quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this will help you:

```
Cursor c = myDB.query(MY_DATABASE_TABLE, "songname","songname like ?" , new String[]{"%"+MATCH_STRING+"%"}, null,"SongHit", null);
```

Comment: You are mostly welcome. Enjoy coding!